# Post json using jquery on express server

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, ajax, express

I want to post a json object to express server.

**Javascript**

```
var task = {
    task: "Do something",
    deadline: "5 am"
};

$.post("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks", task, (data) => {
    console.log(data);
}, "json")
```

**Node.js/Express**

```
var bp = require('body-parser')

app.use(bp.json());

app.post('/api/tasks', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
})
```

When I test the server using Postman, I get the expected output, i.e. it displays the `task` object in the console and also sends it back to the client.

But when I run the above javascript code, it displays an empty object in the console and sends back empty object. What am I missing in the jquery ajax call?

Comment: You aren't sending json. $.ajax default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: isn't `task` a json object?

Comment: No such thing as a json object. json is a string data format

Comment: Okay, so what do I have to do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the application/json header in your request.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'URL', 
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json', 
data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
success: function(res) {
console.log(res)
}
} )
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Is there a way to achieve the same using `$.post()`, instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: $.post will just be a shorthand that&#39;s all $.ajax will also work.

Comment: can you please add the code snippet using `$.post()` to your answer? I am not sure what's the correct syntax to set `contentType` in `$.post()`

Comment: There is no way to add headers using `$.post` you must use $.ajax. also you can parse the results using JSON.parse if you are sending a json response refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)